# Why does my array contain integers I never added? C#

Tags: c#, arrays

```
  int gameTurns = 12;
        do
        {               
            gameTurns -= 1;
            Console.WriteLine("     You have " + (gameTurns) + " attempts left.");
            Console.WriteLine();            
            Console.WriteLine();

            string userEnteredPassword = "";
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a password of 4 digits ");
            userEnteredPassword = Console.ReadLine();

           for (int i = 0; i < numbersToGuess.Length; i++)
            {
                numbersFromPlayer[i] = Convert.ToInt16(userEnteredPassword[i]);                    
                Console.WriteLine(numbersFromPlayer[i]);
            }
```

Note that numbersToGuess was declared like this:

```
 for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++) 
        {
            numbersToGuess[i] = Convert.ToInt16(sequence.Next(9));
            Console.WriteLine(numbersToGuess[i]);
        }
```

When I run my code with the values: 1, 2, 3, 4, 
it prints: 49, 50, 51, 52.

Comment: These seems like UTF values for *character* , `'1','2','3'...`, use `numbersToGuess[i] = (int) Char.GetNumericValue(sequnce.Next(9))`

Answer (score 8):

Yes, because 49 is the UTF-16 code unit for the character '1'.

If you entered "ABCD", it would show 64, 65, 66, 67.

[`Convert.ToInt16(char)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0046aasy(v=vs.110).aspx) is documented as:

> Converts the value of the specified Unicode character to the equivalent 16-bit signed integer.

If you want to convert each character so that '0' became 0, '1' became 1 etc, you could use [`char.GetNumericValue(char)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7k33ktz(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
numbersFromPlayer[i] = (short) char.GetNumericValue(userEnteredPassword[i]);
```

Or if you were happy to trust the player to enter ASCII digits:

```
numbersFromPlayer[i] = (short) (userEnteredPassword[i] - '0');
```

Comment: What's the proper way to convert my string numerical values into the integer they represent to humans?

Comment: @Pokarface: See my updated answer - I've provided two options.

Comment: Thank you. I really don't know why I always get down-voted instead of receiving guidance from the down-voters, but you helped me today :) Maybe my question will help other people with the same doubt but are afraid to ask for fear of being down-voted